# Dupehammer: show the rarest expert badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, dupehammer

When a question is marked as duplicate by a user having dupehammer privileges it seems that their *first-earned* expert badge (applying to the question) is shown in the "marked as duplicate" banner.

Would it be helpful to show the *rarest* matching badge there instead? I'm assuming here that a rarer badge usually pertains to a more specific expertise and, consequently, is better applicable to the question in hand. Therefore, showing this badge will add credibility to the validity of the duplicate and make it more acceptable to the "victim". May prevent a battle or two.

Comment: This is probably very rare, can you give example of a question closed by user with dupehammer in two of its tags? (my point is, if it's really rare, it's not worth the development effort.)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It happens to me frequently at Stack Overflow when closing [c#] + [entity-framework] questions: the [c#] badge is shown. But I see it more often in this area. Fair enough, it probably doesn't happen too often, but I'd be glad with anything that reduces the chance of those tiring battles over closures.

Comment: Are you sure it's the first earned badge that's shown? I'm sure I remember it being alphabetical

Comment: @Cai I don't know the rules, obviously, but anyhow, it's not the rarest badge (or maybe not *always* then).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd a few users have both [`command-line`](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/182/command-line) and [`bash`](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/280/bash) dupehammers on AU, and those tags [go together often](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+%5Bcommand-line%5D+duplicate%3Ayes).

Comment: @muru I see. But does it really make a difference? Does any of those is really so rare it's worth showing it first?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't think I have seen any user complaining about the dupehammer specifically. Certainly not about which tag the dupehammer was applied on 

Comment: But then again, it's entirely possible I missed it. The dupehammer doesn't leave a comment on which I could be replied to, so if OP didn't edit, I probably would never see if they did complain.

Comment: @muru dupehammer, as moderator close vote, can be replied to, just like any editor of the post. (Just made a live test.)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I stand corrected - got the notification